# d3js crashes when I pass a ref to d3.select()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, dom

I am trying to build a graphing component in react with d3. And for the love of god, i could not figure out why it crashes when i'm passing the ref or the selector name or the id to d3.select, when the previous line of code successfully console.log-s all of the above cases.

I have tried binding the function and not binding the function. I have tried different html container to bind to. I invoke the plotting function in ComponentDidMount.

Here is the culprit line: `d3.select('g')`
Both preceding console.log predicatably return the element to which i am trying to bind the graph(full plotting function below).

```
console.log('right before d3 select ref:', this.refs.gelement)
console.log('right before d3 select svg', d3.select('g'))
d3.select('g')
    .datum(dataSeries)
    .call(chartitself);
```

Here is the full function and the element itself

```
<div>
    <svg>
        <g ref="gelement">
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as fc from 'd3fc';


    plot_d3fc_x(data) {
        var dataSeries = data

        var yExtent = fc.extentLinear()
            .accessors([function(d) {
                // console.log(d.y)
                return d.y;
            }])
            .pad([0, 0.2])
            .include([0]);

        var xExtent = fc.extentLinear()
            .accessors([function(d) {
                // console.log(d.x)
                return d.x;
            }])

        var line = fc.seriesSvgLine()
            .crossValue(function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .mainValue(function(d) {
                return d.y;
            })

        var chartitself = fc.chartSvgCartesian(
                d3.scaleLinear(),
                d3.scaleLinear())
            .yDomain(yExtent(data))
            .xDomain(xExtent(data))
            .yOrient('left')
            .plotArea(line);

        console.log('right before d3 select ref:', this.refs.gelement)
        console.log('right before d3 select svg', d3.select('g'))
        d3.select('g')
            .datum(dataSeries)
            .call(chartitself);
    }
```

Data itself and the parsing that goes is in order and i'm thorougly convinced the problem is with d3.select. The error im getting on plot_d3fc_x invocations is `nodes[i].requestRedraw is not a function`
I need some Bostock intervention on this one.

Comment: What does your data look like? Could you reproduce your issue on StackBlitz?

Comment: @viqas thanks for the response! I could not, unfortunately, it is a response from Flask that is(supposed to be) dynamically rendered in this chart, but i format everything before feeding it into this(above) function, so that ````data```` parameter is an array of 600 objects of the form ````0: {x: 0, y: 26.5625}````, ````1: {x: 1, y: 21.25}````, etc...